# Upload file into Assets using URL?

Tags: assets

Is it possible in a front end entry form to pass the URL of a file to an assets field and have it upload that way?  Specifically, I'm trying to move an image from one assets field & upload folder to another in an edit entry form.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you moving an already uploaded file (has an asset id) to another folder?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is there two Assets fields, each specified to upload to different folders? If so, you can just remove the asset id from one field and add it to the other. Also have a look at the actionMoveFile in AssetsController. You might need to make a simple plugin.

Comment: Do you want to _move_ the file (so the file no longer exists in the original location), or do you want it to be _copied_ to the new location?

Comment: Either option would be fine with me.  What's important is that the assets field in the new channel point to the file, whether the field in the original channel still points to it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not currently possible to upload assets via URL, but if we’re only talking about images that are already uploaded into Craft, you could have them selected by their existing asset IDs, rather than URLs, and it would work.

First, go into your Assets field settings and check the “Restrict uploads to a single folder” checkbox.

Then in your entry form, write a UI for selecting an existing asset. Something like this:

```twig
<ul class="asset-selector">
    {% for image in craft.assets.source('images') %}
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="fields[myAssetsField][]" value="{{ image.id }}">
                {% do image.setTransform({ width: 100, height: 100 }) -%}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{ image.title }}">
            </label>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Were you nearby, I would hug you in a manly fashion. 'Cause your smart.